# Ubuntu 13.10 - Rhythmbox 2.99.1 Issues

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox

When I start the Rhythmbox it crashes.
Then I kill the process and restart it, then it works.

It happens every first time I try to run Rhythmbox after turn on my pc.

Does anybody knows something about what is causing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after upgrading to the Rhythmbox newest version I got some problems, so I deactivate all the plugins except the "Notifications" one.

Now it seems to be working properly.

Comment: Zeitgeist plugin is the culprit.

Comment: I read something about that, but just deactivating Zeitgeist didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to version 3 :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jacob/media
>     sudo apt-get update
>      sudo apt-get install rhythmbox

**Important note**: a recent update broke the installation of librhythmbox-core8 (resulting in an error like this: `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ibrhythmbox-core8...deb trying to overwrite...`). Fix this by running the commands below:

> sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core8_3.0.1-1ubuntu2~*.deb
>   sudo apt-get install -f